# How to make a macro button act as if it is being held down, aka, toggled, but not rapid fire?

Tags: keyboard, mouse, macros, gaming, voice-chat

I am a gamer on Windows 10 and many of the multiplayer games I play offer voice chat with a "push to speak" button (usually bound to V), but don't have a "voice activated" mode.

Problem is, holding this key down at the same time as trying to play is very awkward, and less awkward buttons are already in use by other functions necessary to play the game.

Therefore, I would like to make some sort of universal macro that when pressed once, acts like I'm constantly holding down the V key until I press the button again.

I've attempted this with the very simple macro manager that came pre-installed on my computer (Alienware TACTX) and failed to even come close.

I then attempted it on the mouse manager that came with my gaming mouse (Redragon LEGEND) and came close, but it registers more as if I'm rapidly pressing and releasing the V key over and over, and even then I still have to physically hold a key down to get that effect.

So is there any way to do what I'm trying? I would really appreciate some help on this matter.

Comment: Almost all games support setting voice activation instead of using push to talk. That will probably be easier. I don't know either tool you're using. Logitech supports just sending a key down event and you could bind the key up event to a separate button. You probably can do this with a range of other tools as well like AutoIt.

Comment: @Seth ive played a lot of games with built in voice chat function but literally none of them support voice activation without a button. Some prominent examples ive played are TF2 and Warframe. both of them require holding down a button to voice chat. this is the whole reason for my post. i need a way to trick my pc into thinking im holding a button down via a toggle of some sort so that i can constantly voice chat in games like these without actually physically holding the button down all the time.

Comment: You don't need to hold it down all the time, only if you actually want to be heard. Easy to do (in most cases) by e.g. binding it to another mouse button. Which is why at least some games changed to push to talk. Organizing outside of the games with tools like Mumble, TeamSpeak, Discord and so on usually also allow continuous transmission. I already listed some options, in the previous comment, that do what you want. It's up to you to actually do it.